# Different number of rows for different columns per page

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report in which there are 3 columns each contain 3 different subreports in a table. Requirement is 1st subreport column should return 27 rows, 2nd : 25 rows and 3rd:26 rows. Is it possible in SSRS ? If yes How ?
[image: Please refer the pic]

Comment: essentially, you want 3 tables side by side?

Comment: No, these are the 3 columns inside a table

Comment: and columns contains sub reports. Sub reports contains table again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.. using row_number and Mod.

I'm simply generating a list of numbers from 1 - 100 below.. lets assume that this is your dataset.  Create a new column using row_number and partition it by mod 25 (27 or 26 as you require) against this dataset. Now you have a unique value every X number of rows..

```
declare @start int = 1
declare @end int = 100

;with mycte as (

select distinct n = number 
    from master..[spt_values] 
    where number between @start and @end
)

Select 
* 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (mycte.n % 25) ORDER BY (n) )rn  
from mycte

order by 1,2
```

Now in SSRS, against each subreport add this column, add a parent group, grouping by this newly generated row number (RN in this case). Remove any columns that SSRS adds after grouping, but **keep the grouping**..

Set the group property to pagebreak in between each instance of the groups.. Done!

Comment: select top X wont work since Data will not be displayed completely. I want to display everything with above given format

Comment: You said you only wanted x amount of rows per subreport! Did you mean x amount of rows per page on each subreport  and then have a page break?? Or perhaps you could rephrase your question  and make it clearer!

Comment: I m sorry. I meant : 27 rows for 1st column, 25 for 2nd, 26 for 3rd. And after this page break must be there.Again above logic should start

Comment: See my modified answer.